# Getting "403" error while registering an Outgoing Webhook via PostMan

Tags: rest, circuit-sdk

URL :

> https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/webhooks

My Headers :

> - Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - Authorization : Bearer ot-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Body :

> - url - Some URl
> - filter - CONVERSATION.CREATE

Error I am getting :

> "The permission to access this resource is not granted. Scopes ::= [ALL, READ_CONVERSATIONS, READ_USER]"
>
> Plus If i want to send extra filters thn will it be comma separated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a 403, I would suspect a scope error (as mentioned by Roger) or an authentication problem. 
For the first, please show us which scopes are currently selected for the application ; for authentication, can you check if you can make other API calls successfully ?

Here is what it looks like in Postman

[image]

[image]

Comment: Problem identified. It was during the request of the token that the scopes were not properly requested. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app registration contains the scopes that your app is asking for. For a simple outgoing webhook registration you would only need the scope READ_CONVERSATIONS.

See https://github.com/circuit/circuit-REST-bot/blob/master/app.js for an example on how to register for a webhook. This example registers for CONVERSATION.ADD, but CONVERSATION.CREATE is very similar.

If you still have problems please post a code example, or even a link to an app on repl.it.

Comment: For now i have given all the scopes to the bot application. I have to write a simple java http client for it so can u please help me out with a postman request sample.

Comment: I'll add the postman example in another answer so that the code formatting can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example HTTP request to register the webhook. Note that the body is sent as text/plain (which is the default and its header can be omitted). Also note that the callback url is http. https is not yet supported.

```
POST https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/webhooks HTTP/1.1
Host: circuitsandbox.net
Content-Type: text/plain
Authorization: Bearer <token>

url=http://90587c6d.ngrok.io/webhook&filter=CONVERSATION.CREATE
```

and here is a curl command

```
curl -X POST https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/webhooks -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -d "url=http://90587c6d.ngrok.io/webhook&filter=CONVERSATION.CREATE"
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Where do i have to pass the URL and filter ? I tried passing thm in form data, not sure what i am missing.The document says form-data but its still giving the same error. I have reduced the app scope to just Read and Write conversations only. 403 error.

Comment: Url with filter is in the body. See https://www.dropbox.com/s/70ejz6c9yfmmzfy/outgoing%20webhook%20headers.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/70ejz6c9yfmmzfy/outgoing%20webhook%20headers.png?dl=0

Comment: i think you uploaded the same image twice, did see the request body ss.

Comment: I was able to register a webhook using Swagger. the curl looks like this curl -X POST "https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/webhooks" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: Bearer ot-7a5efaOMMITTED" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "url=http%3A%2F%2F90587c6d.ngrok.io%2Fwebhook&filter=CONVERSATION.CREATE"

Comment: Sorry, here is the other link with the body: https://www.dropbox.com/s/actnlqn51u2vc6o/outgoing%20webhook%20body.png?dl=0